# how to open MS Office word in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

in my application, when user click on particular link button, MS word has to open how can i write the code for this. Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to open an existing document, populate a document from ASP.Net or just start Word for the user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to guarantee that a particular application will be opened when a user clicks a link / button on a web page. The application that is opened is determined by the user's browser and operating system settings.

As a developer you can specify the [MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) of the file that you are returning. By doing so you are telling the user's browser what file type is contained in the response. W3Schools provides a pretty good [MIME type by content type list](http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp) and [FILExt](http://filext.com/) also provides the MIME type for the files it lists.

Assuming you specify the appropriate MIME content-type you can be sure the user's browser and operating system will open the file in the "appropriate" application according to their settings. Since you want to open a Word Document file the appropriate MIME content-type will be one of the following:

```
 Extension Type/sub-type
 docx      application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
 doc       application/msword
```

How and where you specify the content-type largely depends on the ASP.NET application type you are working with. If you are writing a ASP.NET Webforms application you'd change the MIME type of the Response object in the Page_Load method. In an ASP.NET MVC application you'd do so in a controller action. In either case the specific line of code is the same.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
```

Answer (score 2):

When you click on a link, redirect the browser to the file mydoc.docx - the browser will open that in Word as long as they have Word installed. You will also need to maek sure your IIS server has the MIME type setup, see [Downloading Docx from IE - Setting MIME Types in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179315/downloading-docx-from-ie-setting-mime-types-in-iis)

If you are generating the Word document on the fly, you will need to set the MIME type so that the browser knows that the response is a word document. I suggest the docx format for generating content.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a Windows Application, this should work...

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("FileName.doc");

For a web application, just redirect to the filename on the hosted server, or use one of the ways as described in the post below...

http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/4-ways-to-send-a-PDF-file-to-the-IE-Client-in-ASPNET-20.aspx