# force download with php issue with docx not with doc

Tags: php, header, mime-types, attachment, doc

I'm using the typical

```
if($ext == "doc" && file_exists($file)) {
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename= '$filename'");
    header('Content-type: application/msword');
    readfile($file);
           }
```

This serves the files perfectly fine.  However when I use:

```
if($ext == "doc" && file_exists($file)) {
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename= '$filename'");
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
    readfile($file);

    }
```

The downloaded document displays errors when I open it in word indicating it is corrupt. However, if I click forward it opens just fine.

How do I make this corrupt file error not occur.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602678/serving-docx-files-through-php Might help.

Comment: And this''click forward' means what to people who have no idea what your system is like?

Comment: @Marc B. I am sorry I typed that terrible. Should be more clear now. I just meant click forward in word.