# serving .docx files through my webserver are corrupt when opened

Tags: php, mime-types

i though i found the answer here:
[Serving .docx files through Php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602678/serving-docx-files-through-php)
But i am still getting the error that the file is corrupt when trying to download and open a docx server via php
Maybe you can see something wrong with my code. The .doc works fine it is the docx that fail.

```
$parts = pathinfo($doc);
$docFile = $userDocRoot.$doc;
if ( !file_exists($docFile) ){
    throw new Exception("Can not find ".$parts ['basename']." on server");
}
if ( $parts['extension'] == 'docx' ){
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats- officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$parts['basename'].'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($docFile);
}else{
   header('Content-type: application/msword');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$parts['basename'].'"');
   readfile($docFile);
}
```

Comment: Is the content of $docFile an actual Word document, or some other format such as html markup?

Comment: yeah ia actually created a doc file and saved it as docx and uploaded it to the server

Comment: You have a space in the Content-Type.  Is that a typo here or in your code as well?

Comment: no just in the cut/paste to this question

Comment: Did you save the file as a `docx` file, or did you rename it to `docx`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for me was to add

```
 $fsize = filesize($docFile);
 header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);
```

Thanks for everyones help

Comment: You got your own answer 2 minutes before I posted the solution. :-)

Answer (score 2):

There were a few extra spaces in your code which would cause it to fail.

Try using this code:

```
$parts = pathinfo($doc);
$docFile = $userDocRoot . $doc;
if(!file_exists($docFile)){
    throw new Exception('Can not find ' . $parts['basename'] . ' on server');
}
if($parts['extension'] == 'docx') {
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $parts['basename'] . '"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($docFile);
} else {
    header('Content-type: application/msword');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $parts['basename'] . '"');
    readfile($docFile);
}
```

If it still doesn't work, try commenting out the `header` and the `readfile` lines, then you will see if there are any errors.

Also, I suggest that you check the filenames against a whitelist, so that people can't download PHP files with passwords in them, etc.

Comment: no difference :-( 
no errors when i comment out header and readfile

Comment: @randy What happens if you don't comment out the `readfile` line?                          Also, if you open the resulting file in Notepad, do you see any errors?

Comment: if i comment out everything but the readfile, i get a bunch of unprintable characters on the page, which makes sense since it is a doc file i guess.

Comment: Can you try creating a test document, save it as a `docx`, and access it through your script?

Comment: @randy Okay. Try accessing it directly though your web browser.

Comment: when i did it in java i went through the same hassle. One thing i had to do it java was response.setContentLength((int) file.length()); Is there something similar in PHP. I assume there is

Comment: Use `header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($docFile));`.

Answer (score 1):

I have just spent a while looking at why my DOCX files are being corrupted and stumbled across this... but I have also found the answer elsewhere...

```
$fsize = filesize($docFile);
header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);
```

This gave me the tools to look for... and the key is that `filesize()` needs the basename of the file to get an accurate file size!

Adapting my code:

```
header("Content-Length: ".filesize(basename($file)));
```

This now offers DOCX (I have set the Content-type to "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document") as intended and I do not have to "repair" the document like others have reported... (I also found that repairing worked)

Comment: This is the correct answer. I just specified `Content-type` and `Content-Disposition`. Adding `Content-Length` solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that's working for me (after about 5 hours of messing around):

```
           // headers to send your file
           header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
           header("Content-Length: " . filesize($original_file));
           header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $new_filename . '"');
           ob_clean();
           flush();
           readfile($original_file);
           exit;
```

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue.

The reason was, that somewhere in my *php-file* two spaces were hidden.

Removing them fixed the issue.

1. Add "`//`" in front of the `header` and `readfile-statements`
2. Write `echo "test";` after the `readfile-statement.`
3. Then look in the HTML source-code, if there are spaces in front of
   the "**test**".