# Asp.net fileupload control hasfile always false for docx files

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

This has inexplicably started happening within the last 6 months or so. This same code used to work with .docx files:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploader" runat="server" BackColor="#620D14" />

if (FileUploader.HasFile)
    ....
```

Any idea what has started happening? Or can someone at least recommend a open source or a cheap alternative control to use? I really don't like this thing anyway because it is impossible to style...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390898/asp-net-c-iis-mime-types-file-upload-conditional) other question might help you.

In relation to an alternative for the FileUpload control I'd recommend you to try [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). It worked great for me and it's much more flexible than the built in file upload control.

Answer (score 5):

if your docx file is empty fileupload.Hasfile returns false but if you open docx file and save something in, you get true from fileupload.HasFile