# FileUpload1.HasFile is False

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

I tried to search for the problem in the internet and I see everyone is asking about the problem for FileUpload control inside the UpdatePanel. First of all, I am not using an UpdatePanel. Below is my code:

**HTML**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" method="post" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="fuImport" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnImport" runat="server" Text="Import" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code Behind**

```
Protected Sub btnImport_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnImport.Click
    If (fuImport.HasFile) Then
        fuImport.SaveAs(My.Settings.FileImportPath & Path.GetFileName(fuImport.FileName))
    End If
End Sub
```

I see that fuImport.HasFile is False, but fuImport.FileName gives just the file name. For e.g., if I choose `c:\1.txt`, it gives just `"1.txt"`.
Can anybody let me know why fuImport.HasFile is False though I have chosen a file?

Comment: That is very strange. I am giving you a +1 on the question. It should definitely return True, according to the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.hasfile.aspx

Comment: Why should the FileUpload.Filename return the absolute filename ("C:\1.txt")? This is the location of the file at the client browser and is not vaild on your server?

Comment: @mortb the issue is not the fact that he gets "1.txt" as opposed to "c:\1.txt". That's immaterial at this point. The important thing is that `HasFile` should definitely return true.

Comment: yes, I see. a bit too fast with the comment...

Comment: Where are you hooking up btnImport to the event handler you have shown?

Comment: @jadarnel27, I am using `Handles btnImport.Click` at the end of the event handler method. I used `OnClick="btnImport_Click"` in the aspx file also. But I believe it is the same and did not help.

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry, I always forget that VB.NET lets you do the event handling that way.  Do you have anything out of the ordinary above the `<html>` (in your `Page` directives, etc)?

Comment: @jadarnel27, I just created a test page and I just modified the form tag. Rest of the things are the default items. The HTML is as below: `<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Test1.aspx.vb" Inherits="ToucheTool.Test1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` above head and body `</html>`

Comment: Are you using Ajax UpdatePanel ?

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi, actually, I was planning to use it. But I saw many people having problems with it and thought of having just a stand alone page which does not have even the script manager. I am using VS 2008. Could you create a new page with form tag as `<form id="form1" method="post" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">` and copy the HTML content and code above to it. Could you let me know what is the HasFile value when you debug? I sent the same to one of my colleagues and waiting for his response. He has gone for lunch. :o).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer. The txt file I was uploading was empty. I edited the text file and then saved by typing something in it. I could not find this anywhere mentioned in the msdn or I am not sure whether I was looking at a wrong place. The suggestion by Kasys in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13397573/740756) helped me.