# asp:FileUpload has no file(flUploadDoc.HasFile = false) on first postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

I have a asp:FileUpload in a user control it works well on second try but gives

```
flUploadDoc.HasFile = false '//Value in debug mode for first try.
```

The structure of page down to file upload is like

master page --> page --> update panel(page) --> control --> update panel(control) --> file upload

My control update panel code is like

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnlAttributes" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        :
        :
            <div class="title">
               Upload:
            </div>
            <div class="input-area">
               &nbsp;<asp:FileUpload ID="flUploadDoc" runat="server" class="upload" />
            </div>
        :
        :
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSavePropertyDocuments" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I also tried to set a PostBackTrigger for the parent update panel.

```
Dim updPanelPropertyRecord As UpdatePanel = Parent.FindControl("updPanelPropertyRecord")
Dim postBackTrigerBtnSave As PostBackTrigger = New PostBackTrigger
postBackTrigerBtnSave.ControlID = btnSavePropertyDocuments.ClientID
updPanelPropertyRecord.Triggers.Add(postBackTrigerBtnSave)
updPanelPropertyRecord.Update()
```

Comment: Check this question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365052/fileupload1-hasfile-is-false?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
```

[Source](http://knowledgebaseworld.blogspot.pt/2009/02/file-upload-not-working-with-update.html)