# Fileupload hasfile returns false on first postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a file upload located in div element. The form element is located in master file. HasFile property always returns false on first postback.

Asp.net Code

```
<div class="form-horizontal center-block" role="form" id="uploadFilesForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="fileUpload" CssClass="col-md-4 control-label">Select Files</asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
               <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fileUpload" AllowMultiple="True" />                 
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="col-md-4 control-label"></asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
               <asp:Button runat="server" id="uploadButton" text="Upload"  CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="uploadButton_Click"/>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>
```

C# Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Page.Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data";   
}
protected void uploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fileUpload.HasFile) // this returns false on first postback
    {
    //more code
    }
}
```

Comment: I found similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365052/fileupload1-hasfile-is-false. But I verified that file has contents and still it can't be uploaded on first click. The same file can be uploaded on second click of Upload button.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code in your OnInit() method:

```
Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
```