# ASP .NET httphandler for .pptx files not working in web.config

Tags: asp.net, .net, httphandler

All of the handlers below work except the one for .pptx files. Has anyone else had this problem?

Here is what is in the web.config:

```
<httpHandlers>
      ...
  <add verb="*" path="*.pdf" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" validate="true"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*.docx" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" validate="true"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*.doc" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" validate="true"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*.pps" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" validate="true"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*.ppt" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" validate="true"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*.pptx" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" validate="true"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is restricting access to the `.pptx` file type, try doing the following:
Create a custom mapping in `IIS` by opening the web site properties in `IIS`, navigating to `Configuration -> Mappings -> Add` and then adding the `.pptx` extension.
This is necessary because, by default, `.NET` does not protect non `Asp.NET` files.

Further information:
[How to restrict the access to a given folder for a specific role](http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/kb/sitefinity-3-x/how-to-restrict-the-access-to-a-given-folder-for-a-specific-role.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that IIS knows about the .pptx extension and has the correct mime-type for it.

[Downloading Docx from IE - Setting MIME Types in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179315/downloading-docx-from-ie-setting-mime-types-in-iis)

http://www.bram.us/2007/05/25/office-2007-mime-types-for-iis/

Comment: In the IIS Manager I went to (local computer) -> Properties -> MIME Types and .pptx was listed.

Comment: Also, this configuration is part of restricting access. I.E. I can't browse to a .docx file without logging in but I can open a .pptx file just fine.

Comment: So your problem is that you can open pptx files, but you can't open docx files? I thought the problem was with pptx files... Besides, `httpHandlers` has nothing to do with restricting access - that is what the `authorization` element is for.