# Allow the final user to access word document on his machine

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-word

I have word documents saved on database as varbinary(max). My final goal is to allow the final user to print it on his machine. That's all I want. And I am very open to all the possible solutions.

**The solutions I've tried so far :**

1. I tried to load it from Database, and display it on the browser. But I found that no browser can display a word document. Unless we
   use **iframes**:
   [How do I render a Word document (.doc, .docx) in the browser using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-to-render-word-documentdoc-docx-in-browser-using-javascript)

   But this solution is not working for my case since, since the final
   user does not have internet connection on his computer. He can only
   access a local network.
2. The second solution I've tried is to retreive the word document from the database, save it to a temp folder and convert it to PDF
   using this library **WordToPDF**, and finally display it to the
   client:

   http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/698727/convert-word-file-to-pdf-using-C-Sharp/

   The problem with this method. It is not working under IIS after
   publishing. Without mentioning the big time that takes to convert a
   word to a PDF.
3. The third solution is to retrieve the document from the database,
   save it to a temp folder, and use Process.Start to open the document
   under Microsoft Word. And again the same problem. It is not working
   under IIS after publishing. **PS: the server is installed on the
   same machine as the final unique client.**

   These solutions to start process under IIS, did not work for me :
   [IIS7 does not start my Exe file by Process Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414514/iis7-does-not-start-my-exe-file-by-process-start)

Why is it so hard to let the client print or even access a document already saved on database ? I am very open to all the possible solutions

Comment: Did you try serving (write binary to response stream) the doc directly? If your [IIS is configured to serve the necessary MIME type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/179315/205233) (which it isn't by default), your browser will try to open the according application (MS Word) or ask to save.

Comment: It worked for me without configuring the MIME type. Thanks